# How to pass data from RecyclerView onItemClick to Activity TabLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem pass or intent data from (activity) to (Fragment) containing 3 (TabLayout ).
How can I transfer data to a specific (TabLayout) of the third that I own.
by RecyclerView onItemClick.

This is code of RecyclerView onItemClick.I was send it From first activity to secand activity like this As follows..

Pass data first activity

```
    public static final String EXTRA_FROM = "FROMPL";

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, 
        com.example.myapplication.Fragmant.StatusFragment.class);
        ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_FROM, clickedItem.getCreator());
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
```

secand activity get data

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 final String FROMPL = i.getStringExtra("FROMPL");
 textfrom.setText(FROMPL);
```

But now like that not work.I don’t know how I can pass it to a specific (TabLayout)to work as Fragment in (MainActivityFargmain).

I want each (TabLayout) in (MainActivityFargmain) has specific  data.

So Anyone have a solution for that؟

all my  code

```
public class MainActivityFargmain extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PageAdapter pageAdapter;
    TabItem tabChats;
    TabItem tabStatus;
    TabItem tabCalls;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_m);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabChats = findViewById(R.id.tabChats);
        tabStatus = findViewById(R.id.tabStatus);
        tabCalls = findViewById(R.id.tabCalls);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorAccent));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                                R.color.colorAccent));
                    }
                } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                                android.R.color.darker_gray));
                    }
                } else {
                    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimary));
                    tabLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                            R.color.colorPrimary));
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivityFargmain.this,
                                R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }
}
```

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numOfTabs;

    PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new ChatFragment();
            case 1:
                return new StatusFragment();
            case 2:
                return new CallFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numOfTabs;
    }
}
```

```
public class StatusFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_status, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_status) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_chats, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_chat) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on " + item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the data to fragment from first activity and you are fetching data from second activity.

But in a proper scenario you should pass the data to second activity. Then after you can fetch it.

```
public static final String EXTRA_FROM = "FROMPL";

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, 
    MainActivityFargmain.class);
    ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);
    detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_FROM, clickedItem.getCreator());
    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```

Fetch the data in **MainActivityFragmain** using below code.

```
 Intent i = getIntent();
 final String FROMPL = i.getStringExtra("FROMPL");

  pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(),FROMPL);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
```

Update your Pager adapter class like below.

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private int numOfTabs;
private String FROMPL;

PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numOfTabs, String FROMPL) {
    super(fm);
    this.numOfTabs = numOfTabs;
    this.FROMPL = FROMPL;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new ChatFragment();
        case 1:
            StatusFragment statusFragment = new StatusFragment();
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();        
            bundle.putString("FROMPL", FROMPL);
            statusFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return statusFragment;
        case 2:
            return new CallFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return numOfTabs;
}
```

}

Comment: Ok Now I can get data into MainActivityFargmain from onItemClick of RecyclerView but now how I can pass data from MainActivityFargmain to StatusFragment Fragment activity?Because I just want use data at on tabLayout

Comment: Fetch the data before **viewpager.setAdapter()** and then you can pass the data to view pager and set that data to specific fragment using bundle.

Comment: Do you have any example of this? I'm a new developer, Sorry about that

Comment: I did it but one problem came up with me I uploaded a picture of it in my question

Comment: Updated the comment check again.

Comment: Now it works great. Thank you very much. I wish to you all the best.